# Problema con cálculo en Java

Tags: java

a raíz de un problema resuelto ayer me ha surgido este que vendría a ser la segunda parte. Solo puedo usar bucles For y clase Math, con el algoritmo acumulador.
Mi principal problema es que aportación e intereses no se inician en 0, y luego no consigo calcular los intereses de la suma del capital, la aportación y los intereses actualizados.
Esto es lo que debería salir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
   double capitalInicial=5000.0;
   double tasa=1.5;
   double aportacion=500.0;
   int anios=5;
   
   for(int i=1; i<=anios; i++) {
   double intereses=capitalInicial*tasa/100;
   System.out.println("Año " + i);
   System.out.println("\t C.Inicial: " + (capitalInicial + aportacion + intereses));
   System.out.println("\t Intereses: " + intereses);
```

Comment: Hola Kop, no entiendo muy bien el problema que tienes, ¿podrías explicarlo algo mejor?

Comment: Hola, lo que tiene que salir por pantalla es lo que viene en la imagen, tengo las variables, pero no consigo hacer los cálculos necesarios para que quede igual. De momento solo consigo que me aparezca bien el interés del año 1, ya que el capital inicial se me suma a la aportación y a los intereses el primer año y no se muestra como debería.

Comment: Si nunca actualizas el valor de `capitalInicial` nunca va a cambiar nada... A juzgar por lo que veo en el resultado esperado, te falta poner `capitalInicial += intereses + aportacion;` al final de tu loop para que en el siguiente paso esté incrementado...

Comment: @Benito-B, gracias, eso me ha servido de ayuda, pero sigo teniendo el problema de que en `Año 1` en vez de salirme solo los 5000.0 de `capitalInicial`  me salen 5575.0 ya que con el código que tengo ahora me suma en `Año 1` `(capitalInicial + aportacion + intereses)`.

Comment: Tienes que sumarlo **después** de imprimirlo...